# How to make a sticky form of paginated checkboxes

Tags: php, forms, sticky

Using PHP, I have a form containing a simple list of items with a checkbox for each.  My issue is that this list must be paginated and as the user pages back and forth, the checkboxes need to be sticky.  Do I need to use ajax and update a session variable for each checkbox click, or is using cookies a better approach?

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Thanks, Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question as it seems nobody has any thoughts on this matter.  In any case, I've gone with a session-based solution.